# How to get an analogous of the (C) function PKCS5_PBKDF2_HMAC in PHP?

Tags: php, hmac, pbkdf2

I am trying to write similar program as [this](https://github.com/jpmens/mosquitto-auth-plug/blob/master/pbkdf2-check.c) but in PHP. It uses the above function, but that function is not available in PHP apparently.

How can I solve this?

I tried to use pbkdf2 function of PHP, but it produces different result than the above function.

Comment: Good question! I think, there is no exact duplicate of this, but probably you can emulate it. Hopefully you'll get also a better answer.